# Black Window Borders and Black terminal in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, launcher, unity-dash, katoolin

help me, I have installed Kali Linux tools and classic menu indicator in Ubuntu 16.04 and after restart all of my menus are lost, terminal is completely black and windows borders are also black, How to restore this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after i installed the latest (beta) graphics driver for my notebook through a PPA. You could try uninstalling them or in case you also use a PPA try to update them through the system updater. In my case updating through the system updater a week later resolved my issue.